# Arquillian ShrinkWrap

Tags: maven, junit, jboss-arquillian

I'm having trouble creating a JUnit test using a pom.xml dependency.

The test are being run with Arquillian

> @RunWith(Arquillian.class)

In this method

> ```
> @Deployment
> public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
> ```

First, I create a JavaArchive with the package of the project I'm testing

> ```
>    JavaArchive merge =  ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class).
>             addPackages(true,
>                     "migrazioneGeaPersistenzaTampone",
>                     "migrazioneGeaPersistenza",
>                     "it.**.mistral.importGEA4.task",
>                     "migrazioneGeaPersistenzaAccess"
>             ).
>            addClasses(java.sql.Connection.class)
>             .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
> ```

Then when I launch the test, there are some missing dependencies

```
Unable to resolve any beans for Types: [class it.**.**.be.service.EnvironmentRootService]
```

present in this dependency

> ```
>       <dependency>
>         <groupId>it.**.mistral</groupId>
>         <artifactId>mistral-be</artifactId>
>         <version>0.1.0</version>
>         <scope>compile</scope>  
>      </dependency>
> ```

I have tried lots of different things to add these dependencies, the best one seems to be using the ShrinkWrap Resolvers  (https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/README.asciidoc, particullarry this paragraph https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/README.asciidoc#resolution-of-artifacts-defined-in-pom-files)

a)

> JavaArchive[] archives = Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile(path_to_pom_file).
>       importDependencies(ScopeType.TEST,ScopeType.COMPILE).
>       resolve().withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);

or

> Maven.resolver().loadPomFromFile("/path/to/pom.xml").importRuntimeDependencies()
>     .resolve().withTransitivity().asFile();

The dependency is ignored in either way (i'm missing something?)

b)

> JavaArchive[] mistral_be = Maven.configureResolver().**workOffline**().
>       resolve("it.**.mistral:mistral-be:0.1.0").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
>       for (int i = 0; i < mistral_be.length ; i++) {
>           merge = merge.merge(mistral_be[i]);
>       }

With a simple

```
System.out.println(merge.toString(true));
```

I can see that all files from dependencies are present! Anyway I use local repository **workoffline**() 
Maybe I am missing some dependencies?

But exiting the method with a

```
return merge;
```

throws a "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/GeneratedMessage....Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage" error.

Then again i tried to add the missing dependecies

> // Tryn'g to add protobuf dependencies
>            JavaArchive[] prto_buf =    Maven.configureResolver().withMavenCentralRepo(true).resolve("com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.3.0").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);
>
> ```
>        for (int i = 0; i < prto_buf.length ; i++) {
>            projectPackages = projectPackages.merge(prto_buf[i]);
>        }
> ```

Throws sameException...
Again , with a simple

```
System.out.println(merge.toString(true));
```

I can see that com.Google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage is present

Extract of dependencies:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>


<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Can anybody help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This smells to me like a classloading issue. Especially considering the fact that you are using embedded container which basically takes everything what's in there from your project classpath.

What is your target container you are deploying your application on? Maybe if you try to run your test there instead of embedded container you will at least see if that is really the problem, or there is still something wrong with your deployment artifact.

Comment: I try to deploy to a managed containere (Jboss 7.1.1), but now i have new problem. Any way i accept the response cause the prblem was the embedded container. Now i will open another thread for the new problem :)

Comment: New question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26453160/arquillian-shrinkwrap-maven-dependencies-in-pom