# Arquillian ShrinkWrap maven dependencies in pom

Tags: java, maven, jboss, jboss-arquillian

So as suggest in another thread ([Arquillian ShrinkWrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316065/arquillian-shrinkwrap/26339445?iemail=1&noredirect=1#26339445)i) have switched to managed container (Jboss AS 7.1) , now the error is different

New dependency managment (see previous link to original question to see )

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-bom</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.5.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then
I have to add

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-core-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Because i have an Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/arquillian/core/api/threading/ExecutorService
```

And now the deploy on local instance of Jboss seems to work fine ( i will test with a simpler test as soon as i have a little time but i think all is fine)
Essentially the problem is to add a jar dependencies present in maven (mistral-be which is not part of this maven project) to the deployed test (see description this question([Arquillian ShrinkWrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316065/arquillian-shrinkwrap/26339445?iemail=1&noredirect=1#26339445))).
Finally i use this code

```
String str = "C:\\IntellijProject\\Import***\\import****\\migrazione****-be\\pom.xml";
    JavaArchive pomFiles = ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class)
            .loadPomFromFile(str).importBuildOutput().as(JavaArchive.class);

/* https://github.com/shrinkwrap/resolver/blob/master/README.asciidoc#resolution-of-artifacts-defined-in-pom-files */
JavaArchive[] mistral_be = Maven.configureResolver().workOffline().resolve("it.****.mistral:mistral-be:0.1.0").withTransitivity().as(JavaArchive.class);

for (int i = 0; i < mistral_be.length ; i++) {
        pomFiles = pomFiles.merge(mistral_be[i]);
```

}

```
pomFiles.as(ZipExporter.class).exportTo(new File ("C:\\temp\\res.zip"));
```

It generate quite a big zip file only to check the result, but while try'n to deploy to jboss 7.1.1

```
18:46:17,003 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (management-handler-thread - 2) JBAS014900: Content added at location C:\jboss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\data\content\bc\b6fd502db2696342419c17a6d2ed82a4176a4e\content
18:46:17,008 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "arquillian-service"
```

I have an error:

```
org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeploymentException: Could not deploy to container: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"postImportBE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".STRUCTURE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"postImportBE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\".STRUCTURE: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment \"postImportBE-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\""}}
```

As i see in the app server log it is

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes.
```

I see in the META_INF of the zipped file directory a lot o files coming from transitive dependencies of mistral-be, so the problem could be this. Is there anyway to generate a JAR file with a valid signature? Or may be i am using a wrong aprroach to solve this problem (contruct jar in another way or similar idea)?
And i'm curios why the dependencies in pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>it.**.mistral</groupId>
    <artifactId>mistral-be</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>  
 </dependency>
```

is not directly import by this instruction? Did i miss something?

```
String str = "C:\\IntellijProject\\Import***\\import****\\migrazione****-be\\pom.xml";
    JavaArchive pomFiles = ShrinkWrap.create(MavenImporter.class)
            .loadPomFromFile(str).importBuildOutput().as(JavaArchive.class);
```

Thank you

Comment: I think the problem is, that all files from all dependent JARs are copied to the new archive and some dependent JAR have a signature, which will also be copied. But this signature is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with pom dependencies I use a WebArchive instead of a JavaArchive for wrapping all the required code generated by ShrinkWrap:

```
String[] mavenLibs = {
            "junit:junit:4.8.1"
};

WebArchive war = ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war");
for (String dependency : mavenLibs) {
    war.addAsLibrary(Maven.resolver().resolve(dependency).withTransitivity().asSingle(JavaArchive.class));
}
```

Using this mecanism I didn't have the issue you described.